# no such file or directory "credentials.json"

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-api

I know other people have had this error, but my issue seems different from any I could find. I am trying to get data from a google sheet using `questsheet.py`, and posting that data to the caller. If I run my questsheet.py file by itself as a standalone, printing the data, it works fine.

If I run it the way it's intended (this is using the evennia engine but it's basically all python with Django/twisted) I get this: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'`

Here is a pastebin of my code:  https://pastebin.com/h2tYhXh5
The issue is at line 48 in the pastebin.

Both my credentials.json file and my questsheet.py file are in the same folder.

I've been learning python for a bit over six months. Still pretty new.

Comment: Since the `.from_client_secrets_file()` method uses an `open(filepath, mode)` statement, have you tried to pass the `credentials.json` absolute filepath to it?